# Custom traffic light algorithm in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to help my mom run a simulation for a smart traffic light switching algorithm for her PhD.

AnyLogic seems promising because I won't have to write the simulation for the traffic itself. Is it possible to have low-level control of the traffic lights based on where cars the cars are?

If not are there any other tools that could help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, in AnyLogic you have full control on how the traffic light works and you also have access to know what is going on with the cars on the road network... But remember that a road traffic simulation with the Personal learning edition only allows for 1 hour of simulation.

Other Software that is open source and quite good, specifically created for traffic simulations is sumo:
http://sumo.dlr.de/index.html